# how to get the mouse's offset when i mouseover a element..use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

this is my code and have a error:

```
    $('#map_canvas').mouseover(function(e){
        console.log(e.offset().left+'  '+e.offset().top)
        })
```

thanks

---

i do this ,and it is always log (0, 0):

```
$('#map_canvas').mouseover(function(e){
var offset = $('#map_canvas').offset(); 
console.log(offset.top+'  '+offset.left); //offset of 'realtiveDiv'
console.log(e.pageX +'  '+e.pageY); // mouse position absolute
})
```

why?

thanks

Comment: -1 because it looks like you've asked almost the same question thrice - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436894/how-to-get-the-mouses-offsetleft-and-top-on-the-maps-when-i-clicked-the-goog and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436969/is-there-any-methord-about-google-maps-api-to-get-the-mouses-offset-when-mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#map_canvas').mouseover(function(e){
    var offset = $('#map_canvas').offset(); 
    var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var y = e.pageY - offset.top;

    console.log('X: '+x+' Y: '+y); //you want this

    //console.log(offset.top+'  '+offset.left); //offset of 'realtiveDiv'
    //console.log(e.pageX +'  '+e.pageY); // mouse position absolute
});
```

---

Update:
if `offset.top` and `offset.left` log (0, 0), it means that the element whose `offset` you are logging, starts at (0, 0). In other words, the element is at the top left corner of the screen.

Comment: i want to get the mouse's offset(relative to '#map_canvas'),how to do this ?  thanks